# meteor add joshowens:accounts-entry package in Nitrous.io box - no templates added or visible

Tags: meteor, nitrousio, meteor-accounts

I'm using a Nitrous.io IDE and attempted to add Josh Owens accounts-entry package.

The package installs (it's listed in my packages), but all the files that are supposed to come with it are not visible. It is definitely installed because if I go to the /sign-in url it renders the sign-in page complete with the form.

I have tried the "show hidden" option and searched through all the folders but can't find any of the files meant to come with the package.

I've tried manually adding the files, but these are being superseded by the original files that have been installed.

Any ideas of where they are would be greatly appreciated or is it simply a case that if you are using a Nitrous.io IDE and install this package you cannot access the files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some significant research, it turns out that at the time of writing, packages added via **meteor add {package-name}** with customisable files, cannot be customised. It has to do with the way the Nitrous.io box is provisioned on its Unix Linux OS.

Hopefully Nitrous.io will address this in due course. I have reached out to them.

In the interim the solution is to build a custom package from scratch!